# Why does the python shell require a restart to import newly added variables to a module?

Tags: python

Suppose in `main.py` I have

```
from tools import myconstant
```

and in `tools.py` I have:

```
myconstant = 15
```

Now I add something to `tools.py`:

```
myconstant = 15
myotherconstant = 25
```

Save the file and in `main.py` I run (still from the same python session):

```
from tools import myotherconstant
```

which throws an error. If I restart my python session it works. Why is that? I know that usually, one would run the main file from a fresh session and never have this 'problem' but I am still curious as to why python cannot detect changes in files. If I change the contents of a CSV file and read it in again it would reflect the updated data. What is the difference here?

There is no problem to solve here, I am just asking for clarification of python concepts :) Some minimal examples that demonstrate the inner workings would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module)

Comment: Python caches imports so subsequent expensive imports don't need to be entirely reloaded again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [does python cache imported files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57346840/does-python-cache-imported-files)

Comment: Another related question: [Can Python recognize changes to a file that it is running interactively?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53550752/2745495)

Answer (score 1):

Modules are only checked at load time which is a good thing, You can use reload()

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(tools.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

A restart is not specifically required, you just need to reload the module

Python will cache the modules that are imported

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache)

> The first place checked during import search is `sys.modules`. This
> mapping serves as a cache of all modules that have been previously
> imported, including the intermediate paths.

You can delete the module from the cache by deleting the dictionary key from `sys.modules` and do the import again. Although, this is not the recommended approach (as other modules may hold references to it).

You should use `importlib.reload`
From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload)

> Reload a previously imported module. The argument must be a module
> object, so it must have been successfully imported before. **This is
> useful if you have edited the module source file using an external
> editor and want to try out the new version without leaving the Python
> interpreter.**

Example,

```
import xyz # reload this
import importlib
importlib.reload(xyz)
```

Or

```
from xyz import pqr
import importlib
import sys
importlib.reload(sys.modules.get('xyz')
```

In your example, you need to do

```
import importlib
import sys
importlib.reload(sys.modules.get('tools'))
```

Doing a restart will clear the cache too, but it is not required.